# Routing issue with iproute2, two gateways and two network interfaces

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, gateway, iproute2

**I am trying to setup a layer 3 iptables firewall, with two interfaces.**

My firewall has two physical interfaces : eno0, connected to my ISP's gateway, and eno1, connected to my local network gateway.

**The network setup is described below:**

```
ISP gateway: aaa.aaa.127.17
            |
            |
            | subnet: aaa.aaa.127.16/30
            |
            |
            | eno0: aaa.aaa.127.18
-----------------------------
|                           |
|       my firewall         |
|                           |
-----------------------------
            | eno1: 172.20.4.1
            |
            |
            | subnet: 172.20.4.0/30
            |
            |
            | 172.20.4.2
-----------------------------
|                           |
|     my local gateway      |
|                           |
-----------------------------
             | bbb.bbb.137.1
             |
             |
             | subnet: bbb.bbb.137.0/24
             |
             | 
 Laptop: bbb.bbb.137.20
```

(aaa.aaa.127.16/30 and bbb.bbb.137.1/24 are public IP ranges)

**I am trying (unsuccessfully) to get internet access from my laptop. Currently, I have no filtering rules in iptables. So the problem lies in routing configuration.**

I appended `1 rt2` at the end `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, and here is the relevant part of my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto eno0
iface eno0 inet static
    address aaa.aaa.127.18
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    gateway aaa.aaa.127.17

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 172.20.4.1
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    post-up ip route add 172.20.4.0/30 dev eno1 src 172.20.4.1 table rt2
    post-up ip route add bbb.bbb.137.0/24 dev eno1 src 172.20.4.1 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 172.20.4.2 dev eno1 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add from 172.20.4.1/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 172.20.4.1/32 table rt2
```

On my local gateway, I have a static route that redirects all traffic to 172.20.4.1 (if the destination IP isn't in the ARP table).

From the firewall, I can ping:

- my ISP gateway (aaa.aaa.127.17)
- Google (8.8.8.8)
- my local gateway (172.20.4.2)

However, the problem is I cannot ping my laptop (bbb.bbb.137.20) from the firewall.

From the laptop, I can ping my local gateway but not my firewall.
From my local gateway, I can ping my firewall but not Google.

**So it seems like my firewall does not know how to route traffic to bbb.bbb.137.0/24. What am I missing?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using 2 routers - ```local gateway``` and ```firewall```? What OS/Device are you using on Firewall?

Comment: My local gateway connects together 30+ switches, so it is where I want the local routing to occur (for many reasons, including hardware optimizations that makes it much, much faster than my firewall). As for the firewall, I would do without it if my local gateway's integrated firewall was better and supported NAT - which it does not. So I am afraid I need both. To answer your question, the firewall is a Dell server running Debian 9. Anyway, I figured it out as explained below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. I changed part of `/etc/network/interfaces` and it worked:

```
auto eno0
iface eno0 inet static
    address aaa.aaa.127.18
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    gateway aaa.aaa.127.17

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 172.20.4.1
    netmask 255.255.255.252
    post-up ip route add bbb.bbb.137.0/24 via 172.20.4.2
    post-up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 172.20.4.2
    post-up ip route add 192.168.0.0/16 via 172.20.4.2
    post-up ip route add 172.16.0.0/12 via 172.20.4.2
```

Also, there is no need to change `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.